# PHP Associative Array Returned From JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json, string, associative

I'm new to this aspect of programming and am trying to get to grips with Associative Arrays.

(In PHP)

After an API call I'm getting a JSON string returned and I've turned it into json_decode array.

I'm seriously struggling with the following array (Excerpt shown from a print_r statement):

```
Array (
    [GBP-USD] => stdClass Object (
        [val] => 1.6649
    )
    [GBP-EUR] => stdClass Object (
        [val] => 1.2522
    )
    [GBP-CAD] => stdClass Object (
        [val] => 1.8236
    ) etc
```

Basically a Currency to Currency code and its associated conversion rate.

I'm trying to extricate each Currency to Currency code and the associated rate, then turn the rate into  a 2 decimal place float and display a list with currency code and rate side by side;
I'm fine with the last two bits but the array element associated with the currency code does not have an associated value, its value is an object, so how do I access the value of the 'val' element in the array AND the associated currency code at the same time?

I've tried this approach (and about 100 others) but it is falling over when the $element['value'] is reached because the value is an object:

```
while ($element = each($curr_data)){
    echo $element['key'].':' .$element['value']. '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: FYI if you *want* an associative array with [`json_decode`](http://au2.php.net/json_decode), provide `true` as the 2nd argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of objects so to access the property you could do this.

```
foreach ($curr_data as $key => $item){
    echo $key.':' .$item->val. '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: After setting the object as variable $item, does its value name have to be the same as in the array, ie it  has to be item->"val"? (Quotation marks used for emphasis)

Comment: Yes, "val" is the property name of the object

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at PHP documentation here [PHP: json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

If you want to decode JSON as an associative array, pass `true` as the second argument.